# How Can I Fetch Excel Sheet In Android?

Tags: android, excel, sqlite

How can I fetch the username & password from the Excel sheet in an Android project?

I don't had to register, directly login but login will be created in Excel file externally.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/19/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/

Comment: Do you want to read data from excel?

Comment: can you explain your exact purpose? if you want to write login details in user's memory better go for sharedpreferences..

Comment: how are you planning to update the excel ?? where are you going to store the excel sheet? on server? or client's device?

Comment: on server. i m not having that much knowledge of android.

Comment: @Girija - you will have to create a webservice to pass data between server and android app.. the code to update the excel sheet should be present n webservice.. for basics of creating client-server apps.. you can try this tutorial.. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/